# Search into a database using a form with various options

Tags: database, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an .asp page and I am using VBscript. basically I have a database with country, partner type and phone columns. I know how to load these into a recordset and display them into an .asp page.

I am using a dropdown for Partner Type and Country, and I am using a label for the phone.

**Now what I am trying to do is that when a user selects a partner type, the information related to that partner type will show.**  I really dont know from where to start :/ I am not askign for someone to do all this for me, but i need some tips or maybe online tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out it is not easy to answer because the question is so wide. I'll try to make a simplified code example and then you surely can fill in the remaining bits.

`<%
     dim country
     dim partnerType
     dim phone`

```
 country = request("country")
 partnerType = request("partnerType")
 dim phone = request("phone")

'Get more information from database
    Set objConnect                      = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnect.ConnectionTimeout        = 580
    objConnect.Open "myConnectionString"
    set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRS .Open "select * from yourTable", objConnect, , , adCmdText


while not objRS.EOF 
    response.write "found record in database"
loop

%>
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
     <label>Country</label><select name="country"><option value="se">Sweden</option></select>
     <label>PartnerType</label><select name="partnerType" onChange="PtypeChanged();"><option value="1">Reseller</option><option value="2">International</option></select>
     <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
</form>
<script>
function PtypeChanged(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're looking to create dependent dropdown lists.  There's an example with a demo here:

http://www.aspkey.net/aspkey/_articles/asp/showarticle.asp?id=100